# Can't send hidden embed message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to send a "hidden" message, which will only be visible to message author:

```
#ping
@slash.slash(name='ping', description="Check Bot's response time", guild_ids=guild_ids)
@commands.has_role(804318858873536522)
async def ping(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=":ping_pong:Pong!:ping_pong:", colour=discord.Colour.blue(), description=f':ballot_box_with_check:Response time is **{client.latency}**ms')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
```

When I am executing this command I am getting this error:

```
Embed/File is not supported for `hidden`!
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

*Hidden message is a message which is only can be seen by author. Example: [image]

Comment: There is a keyword argument called `ephemera` which takes a `bool` Indicates if the message should only be visible to the user. Not sure if it's available in your third party package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. It was very stupid actually. I needed to stop my bot instance which is on the hosting. Slash commands won't work until only 1 instance is active

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this error message you got:

```
Embed/File is not supported for `hidden`!
```

I think this answers your question, but I'm not totally sure.